# Make some extra space when using TikZ fit package

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using the `fit` package to wrap nodes inside a rectangle, as the code shown below. Is there any way to make some extra space between the node `client 3` and the bottom edge of the box?

Code:

```
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, calc, shapes, arrows}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figure}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture} [title/.style={font=\fontsize{18}{18}\color{black!45}},
        server/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=blue!23, rounded corners, minimum height=8em},
        client/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=green!23, rounded corners, minimum height=2em},
        dot/.style={circle, fill=black, minimum size=2pt, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=2pt}]
        % Place nodes
        \node [title] (frontend) at (0, 10) {Clients};
        \node [client] (client1) at (0, 9.25) {Client 1};
        \node [client] (client2) at ($(client1) + (270:1.15)$) {Client 2};
        \node [client] (client3) at ($(client2) + (270:1.15)$) {Client 3};
        \node [draw=black!50, fit={(frontend) (client1) (client2) (client3)}] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Clients graph}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: @GonzaloMedina's answers your question, but if you don't mind having additional spacing all around you could just add `inner sep=<amount>` to the `fit` node, or an `outer sep=<amount>` to one of the `client` nodes.

Comment: Surely it's simpler to set a value for the innner/outer sep values for the fitted node. \node [draw=black!50, inner sep = 1em, fit={(frontend) (client1) (client2) (client3)}] {}; (I couldn't comment for some reason so posted an answer instead)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using the `calc` library you can add some value to the y component of the node.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, calc, shapes, arrows}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture} [title/.style={font=\fontsize{18}{18}\color{black!45}},
        server/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=blue!23, rounded corners, minimum height=8em},
        client/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=green!23, rounded corners, minimum height=2em},
        dot/.style={circle, fill=black, minimum size=2pt, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=2pt}]
        % Place nodes
        \node [title] (frontend) at (0, 10) {Clients};
        \node [client] (client1) at (0, 9.25) {Client 1};
        \node [client] (client2) at ($(client1) + (270:1.15)$) {Client 2};
        \node [client] (client3) at ($(client2) + (270:1.15)$) {Client 3};
        \node [draw=black!50, fit={(frontend) (client1) (client2) ($(client3.south)+(0,-3pt)$)}] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Clients graph}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am playing with your code, and just wonder how I should apply the same principle to the case where `client 1`, `client 2`, and `client 3` are placed **horizontally** in a box. Only increasing their `y` components does not seem to work, as the width of the outer box shrinks.

Comment: @Skyork sure it works: try `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, calc}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture} [client/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=green!23, rounded corners, minimum height=2em}]
        \node [client] (client1) at (0, 9.25) {Client 1};
        \node [client,right=of client1] (client2) {Client 2};
        \node [client,right=of client2] (client3) {Client 3};
        \node [draw=black!50, fit={(client1) (client2) ($(client3.east)+(0,-20pt)$)}] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}`.

Comment: @Skyork better to use the `south east` anchor in my previous code; the last node in the `fit` option should be `($(client3.south east)+(0,-3pt)$)`.