# how to draw a container box in latex around automata?

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes

This is my tikz code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.geometric,arrows,fit,calc,positioning,automata,}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=5 cm, scale = 0.6, transform shape]

  \node[initial,state] (A)                                  {$q_0$};
  \node[state]         (B) [right of=A,node distance=3 cm]              {$q_1$};
  \node[state]         (C) [right of=B,node distance = 6.5 cm]              {$q_2$};
  \node[state]         (D) [below right of=B]       {$q_3$};
  \node[state]         (E) [below right of=D]                   {$q_5$};
  \node[state]         (F) [below left of=D]                {$q_4$};


  \path[->] (A) edge [above]            node [align=center]             {}  (B)
        (B) edge [loop above]       node [align=center]             {}  (B)
        edge [bend right,below]     node [align=center]         {}  (C)
        edge [left]             node [align=center]         {}  (D)
        (C) edge [loop above]       node [align=center]         {}  (C)
        edge [bend right,right]     node [above,align=center]       {}  (B)
        edge [right]            node [align=center]             {} (D)
        (D) edge [bend left,right]      node [align=center]         {} (E)
        edge [bend right,left]      node [pos=0.4,align=center]     {} (F)
        (E) edge [bend left]        node [pos=0.2,align=center]     {} (D)
        (F) edge [bend right,above]     node [pos=0.6,align=center]     {} (D)
        edge [bend left]        node [pos=0.7,align=center]     {} (A);


\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

And this is the output:
[image]

I want to draw container boxes (possibly with dashed border) around {q1,q2,q3} and {q3,q4,q5} states and label them. How to do that in tikz?

I want the following output:

[image]

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is a job for the `fit` library.

### 1. Initial Guess:

Using the `fit=` and specifying the nodes around which you want the box fit:

```
\node [draw=red, fit= (B) (C) (D)] {};
\node [draw=red, fit= (D) (E) (F)] {};
```

gets you pretty close to what you want:

[image]

Now it is just a matter of adjusting the boxes.

### 2. Add `inner sep=`

Note that the boxes are tightly fit around the specified nodes. So, that makes me think that we should increase the `inner sep`.
So if you add `inner sep=0.75cm` to the first rectangle, and `inner sep=1.00cm` to the second rectangle:

```
\node [draw=red, fit= (B) (C) (D), inner sep=0.75cm] {};
\node [draw=red, fit= (D) (E) (F), inner sep=1.00cm] {};
```

you get:

[image]

### 3. Tweaking: Line Styles:

You also asked for a dashed box, so adding `dashed` to the list options, and making the lines thicker with `ultra thick` we get:

[image]

Perhaps using different colors for the lines and adding some fill color with an opacity will make the group easier to see:

[image]

### 4. Adding a Label

You can add a label is to name the box produced by the `fit=` option and `anchor` the label to one of the points along the boundary:

[image]

### 5. Tidying Up:

Now it looks like we are done. But wait, the overlap of the blue box with the red box is not quite symmetrical. Seems as if we could just stretch the blue box on to the left slightly things would look much better.  So if somehow we could convince the `fit` library that the node `(F)` (corresponding to `q4`) was a bit to the left, then things would have worked. Basically we need to [Make some extra space when using TikZ fit package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73129/make-some-extra-space-when-using-tikz-fit-package/73130#73130). So, lets define a new point a bit to the left of the west side of `(F)`:

```
\coordinate (F') at ($(F.west) + (-1.75em,0)$);
```

then we just give `(F')` to the `fit` library instead of `(F)`.

### 6. Use layers

Using `layers` allows you to place the fit in the `background` layer so that the drawing elements are on top and do not have any opacity effects.

[image]

### Note:

- You really should use node names which correspond to the nodes. Here `Q0`, `Q1`, ... would have been ideal.  Updated solution `with layers` has these.
- The updated `layers` solution required additional tweaks in the placement of the bounding box -- not sure why.

The complete code is below, but basically all I did was add these lines:

```
    \coordinate (F') at ($(F.west) + (-1.75em,0)$);
    \node (Y) [draw=blue, fit= (D) (E) (F'), inner sep=1.00cm, 
            dashed, ultra thick, fill=blue!10, fill opacity=0.2] {};
    \node [yshift=3.0ex, blue] at (Y.south) {Label B};
```

### Code: Without `layers`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.geometric,arrows,fit,calc,positioning,automata,}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=5 cm, scale = 0.6, transform shape]

  \node[initial,state] (A)                                     {$q_0$};
  \node[state]         (B) [right of=A,node distance=3 cm]     {$q_1$};
  \node[state]         (C) [right of=B,node distance = 6.5 cm] {$q_2$};
  \node[state]         (D) [below right of=B]                  {$q_3$};
  \node[state]         (E) [below right of=D]                  {$q_5$};
  \node[state]         (F) [below left of=D]                   {$q_4$};


  \path[->] (A) edge [above]            node [align=center]         {} (B)
            (B) edge [loop above]       node [align=center]         {} (B)
                edge [bend right,below] node [align=center]         {} (C)
                edge [left]             node [align=center]         {} (D)
            (C) edge [loop above]       node [align=center]         {} (C)
                edge [bend right,right] node [above,align=center]   {} (B)
                edge [right]            node [align=center]         {} (D)
            (D) edge [bend left,right]  node [align=center]         {} (E)
                edge [bend right,left]  node [pos=0.4,align=center] {} (F)
            (E) edge [bend left]        node [pos=0.2,align=center] {} (D)
            (F) edge [bend right,above] node [pos=0.6,align=center] {} (D)
                edge [bend left]        node [pos=0.7,align=center] {} (A);

        % Following lines added
        \node (X) [draw=red, fit= (B) (C) (D), inner sep=0.75cm, 
                dashed, ultra thick, fill=red!20, fill opacity=0.2] {};

        \coordinate (F') at ($(F.west) + (-1.75em,0)$);
        \node (Y) [draw=blue, fit= (D) (E) (F'), inner sep=1.00cm, 
                dashed, ultra thick, fill=blue!10, fill opacity=0.2] {};
        \node [yshift=3.0ex, blue] at (Y.south) {Label B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

### Code: with `layers`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.geometric,arrows,fit,calc,positioning,automata,}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%% -------------------------------------- Declare the layers
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=5 cm, scale = 0.6, transform shape]

    \node[initial,state] (Q0)                                      {$q_0$};
    \node[state]         (Q1) [right of=Q0,node distance=3 cm]     {$q_1$};
    \node[state]         (Q2) [right of=Q1,node distance = 6.5 cm] {$q_2$};
    \node[state]         (Q3) [below right of=Q1]                  {$q_3$};
    \node[state]         (Q5) [below right of=Q3]                  {$q_5$};
    \node[state]         (Q4) [below left  of=Q3]                  {$q_4$};

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{main}
        \path[->, thick] 
            (Q0) edge [above]            node [align=center]         {} (Q1)
            (Q1) edge [loop above]       node [align=center]         {} (Q1)
                 edge [bend right,below] node [align=center]         {} (Q2)
                 edge [left]             node [align=center]         {} (Q3)
            (Q2) edge [loop above]       node [align=center]         {} (Q2)
                 edge [bend right,right] node [above,align=center]   {} (Q1)
                 edge [right]            node [align=center]         {} (Q3)
            (Q3) edge [bend left,right]  node [align=center]         {} (Q5)
                 edge [bend right,left]  node [pos=0.4,align=center] {} (Q4)
            (Q5) edge [bend left]        node [pos=0.2,align=center] {} (Q3)
            (Q4) edge [bend right,above] node [pos=0.6,align=center] {} (Q3)
                 edge [bend left]        node [pos=0.7,align=center] {} (Q0);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        % Following lines added
        \coordinate (Q1') at ($(Q1.north west) + (-6.0em,10.0ex)$);
        \coordinate (Q2') at ($(Q2.north east) + ( 6.0em,10.0ex)$);
        \coordinate (Q3') at ($(Q3.south) + (0.0em,-7.0ex)$);
        \node (X) [draw=red, fit= (Q1') (Q2') (Q3'), inner sep=0.75cm, 
                dashed, ultra thick, fill=red!20, fill opacity=0.2] {};

        \coordinate (Q3') at ($(Q3.north) + (0.0em,3.0ex)$);
        \coordinate (Q4') at ($(Q4.west) + (-8.0em,-4.0ex)$);
        \coordinate (Q5') at ($(Q5.east) + ( 7.0em,0)$);
        \node (Y) [draw=blue, fit= (Q3') (Q5') (Q4'), inner sep=1.00cm, 
                dashed, ultra thick, fill=blue!10, fill opacity=0.2] {};
        \node [yshift=3.0ex, blue] at (Y.south) {Label B};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) how can I put labels for them?

Comment: @user1280282: have updated solution to add a label as well.

Comment: Is there any way to change the width and height of the container box?

Comment: @user1280282: Have updated solution to adjust width of box that as well.

Comment: Is there a way to place the "fitted" elements be on top of the drawn "fit-rectangle"? It's a beautiful solution, which I right now put into practice in the course of learning TikZ. I just wonder, if I could place the arrows and symbols (in black) on top of the drawn rectangular boxes in order to _not_ desaturate the main graph...

Comment: @LCsa: Yep you can use layers to specify that the bounding boxes are int eh background. I'll update the solution once I get some time. Hopefully sometime tonight...

Comment: Wow, that's very nice of you! :) "Layers" is a good keyword for a newbie. ;)

Comment: @LCsa: Updated to include use of `layers`. Apologies for the delay.