# How put tick and cross mark around a node in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-trees, fit

I want to draw something like this:

[image]

This is my tikz code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}


\tikzstyle{bag} = [text width=8em,
text centered]

\tikzstyle{bag_mod} = [text width=2em,
text centered]

\tikzstyle{bag_rect} = [draw=black,rectangle, black,text width=8em,
text centered]

\tikzstyle{bag1} = [draw=black,rectangle, black,text width=4em,
text centered]



\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[-,>=stealth',level/.style={sibling distance = 2.5cm/#1,
  level distance = 1cm}] 
\node [bag] {$||$}
    child{node[bag] {$\&\&$}
      child{node[bag] {$enabled$}}
      child{node[bag] {$\&\&$}
          child{node[bag1,left] {$tcas\_eq$}}
          child{node[bag_rect,right] {$intent\_not\_known$}}
       }
    }
    child{node[bag] (A) {$!$}
      child{node[bag] (B) {$tcas\_eq$}}
    }
; 
%\node [draw=red, fit= (A) (B)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And this is the output:

[image]

I have two questions:

1. How to put tick and cross mark as shown in the first figure?
2. How to draw a rectangle containing two node? Example: I want to draw a single rectangle enclosing `!` and `tcas_eq` (right side of the root).
   How to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way would be to label the nodes so that you have a coordinate to refer to them and then add a node with the desired symbol, and similarly to draw a rectangle around some other nodes.

[image]

### Notes:

- I am not really sure why I needed to add the `xshift`. For some reason the nodes are large than they should be (perhaps an `inner sep`, `outer sep` issue).
- The `Cross` is from [How can I get a big cross to denote a generalized cartesian product?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28150/how-can-i-get-a-big-cross-to-denote-a-generalized-cartesian-product/28151#28151).

### Refernece:

- Here is a brief tutorial style answer showing the use of the `fit` library: [How to draw nested nodes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85536/how-to-draw-nested-nodes/)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}

%\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}


\tikzstyle{bag} = [text width=8em,
text centered]

\tikzstyle{bag_mod} = [text width=2em,
text centered]

\tikzstyle{bag_rect} = [draw=black,rectangle, black,text width=8em,
text centered]

\tikzstyle{bag1} = [draw=black,rectangle, black,text width=4em,
text centered]

\newcommand{\Cross}{$\mathbin{\tikz [x=1.4ex,y=1.4ex,line width=.2ex, red] \draw (0,0) -- (1,1) (0,1) -- (1,0);}$}%

\newcommand{\Checkmark}{$\color{green}\checkmark$}



\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[-,>=stealth',level/.style={sibling distance = 2.5cm/#1,
  level distance = 1cm}] 
\node [bag] {$||$}
    child{node[bag] (X0) {$\&\&$}
      child{node[bag] (enabled) {$enabled$}}
      child{node[bag] (X1) {$\&\&$}
          child{node[bag1,left] (X2) {$tcas\_eq$}}
          child{node[bag_rect,right] (intent) {$intent\_not\_known$}}
       }
    }
    child{node[bag] (A) {$!$}
      child{node[bag] (B) {$tcas\_eq$}}
    }
; 

\node at ([xshift=2.5em]enabled.north west)  {\Cross};
\node at ([xshift=3.0em]X0.north west)  {\Cross};
\node at ([xshift=-0.5em]X2.north west)  {\Cross};

\node at ([xshift=-3.0em]X1.north east)  {\Checkmark};
\node at ([xshift=1em]intent.north east)  {\Checkmark};

% Use fit library
%\node [draw=blue, ultra thick, fit=(A) (B), shape=rectangle, inner sep=0pt] {};

\draw [draw=blue, ultra thick] 
    ([shift={(-2.0em,-0.25ex)}]A.north) rectangle ([xshift=2.0em]B.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to use `label` option in your nodes. Here I have used `\tikzset` instead of `\tikzstyle`. I have also included additional styles `bag2` and `bag_rect2`. I have also replaced your `text width` and `text centered` combo with `align=center` since there is no very long nodes in your example. But you can always ignore this depending on your actual use case. The positions of the `x`'s and check marks are not as prettily positioned but you can always node positioning as in Peter Grill's answer.

### The modified code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\tikzset{
bag/.style = {align=center, outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt, 
              label=above left:\color{red}$\times$},
bag2/.style = {align=center, outer sep=0pt, 
              inner sep=0pt,label=north east:\color{green}$\checkmark$},
bag_mod/.style = {align=center},
bag_rect/.style = {draw=black,rectangle, black,
                  label=above right: \color{green}$\checkmark$},
bag_rect2/.style = {draw=black,rectangle, black,
                  label=above left: \color{red}$\times$},
bag1/.style = {draw = black, rectangle, black, align = center}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[-,>=stealth',level/.style={sibling distance = 2.5cm/#1,
  level distance = 1cm}] 
\node [bag_mod] {$||$}
    child{node[bag] {$\&\&$}
      child{node[bag] {$enabled$}}
      child{node[bag2] {$\&\&$}
          child{node[bag_rect2,left] {$tcas\_eq$}}
          child{node[bag_rect,right] {$intent\_not\_known$}}
       }
    }
    child{node[bag_mod] (A) {$!$}
      child{node[bag2] (B) {$tcas\_eq$}}
    }
; 
%\node [draw=red, fit= (A) (B)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### The output

[image]