# How to draw this cross?

Tags: pdftex, line

The image below is used for factoring quadratic polynomial. How to draw it in Latex (only the part enclosed by the red rectangle)? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100272/4301
\newcommand{\Cross}{%
    \mathbin{%
        \tikz [x=2.0ex,y=2.0ex,line width=.3ex, black] \draw (0,0) -- (1,1) (0,1) -- (1,0);
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{array}{r@{}c@{}l}
        2y & & 3          \\
           & {}\Cross{} & \\[-0.75ex]
        3y & & 5          \\
    \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```