# TikZ Graph with a circle alround some of it's vertices

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-graph

I want to draw the following Graph with the tikz package and/or tkz-graph package, but I'm still very new to this. Could someone please help me? :)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you able to do any part of it? If so, can you add that code to your question?

Comment: No, I'm afraid, I don't even know how to approach this. :/ I've only made really really simple graphs until now.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8890/tikz-how-to-draw-boxes-around-set-of-nodes , related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59012/how-to-use-fit-to-frame-the-nodes-and-labels and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73129/make-some-extra-space-when-using-tikz-fit-package , see also http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/fit/

Comment: You want to check out the fitting library `fit` of TikZ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one attempt using tikz:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw(0,0)--(2,0)--(0,1)--(2,1)--(0,0);
      \draw(0,3)--(2,3);
      \draw[very thin, double distance=2pt](0.6,2.2)--(1.4,1.6);
      \draw[very thin, double distance=2pt](0.6,1.6)--(1.4,2.2);
      \foreach \y/\lab in {0/1,1/2,3/h} {
          \filldraw(0,\y) circle[radius=2pt]node[left]{$v_{\lab}$};
      }
      \foreach \y/\lab in {0/n-h+1,3/n,-2/h+1} {
          \filldraw(2,\y) circle[radius=2pt]node[right=3mm]{$v_{\lab}$};
      }
      \filldraw(2,1) circle[radius=2pt];
      \node at (0,2) {$\vdots$};
      \node at (2,2) {$\vdots$};
      \node at (2,-1) {$\vdots$};
      \draw[rounded corners] (1.7,-2.3) rectangle (2.3,3.3);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is awsome! Thaks a lot!!! :) Is there maybe also some way to change the size of the vertecies to 8pt and the thickness of the edges to 1.5pt?

Comment: Glad it's helpful. This code, which uses tikz, is highly configurable. I'd recommend looking at the the [tikz manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) -- or `texdoc tikz` from the command-line. The tikz manual is huge but very readable. The radius of the vertices is controlled by `radius=2pt` so if you instead use `radius=4pt` then the vertices will have a  diameter of `8pt`. The line width can be controlled with `\draw[line width=1.5pt] ....`. This is very similar to `\draw[ultra thick]...` which gives lines of thickness `1.6pt`.

Comment: Both this answer and the answer by @torbjørn-t are very instructive, but isn't this and example of vampire feeding? (no offense intended, this seems to be standard terminology ;))

Comment: @Marijn I've not come across the term "vampire feeding" before:) The two obvious interpretations would make either the OP or me the vampire! Assuming/hoping that you mean the form, I often comment on posts by saying that 'some people take exception to questions of the form "Please draw this for me"', which may be what you are getting at. In this instance I thought that the OP genuinely did not know where to start and I am trying to avoid doing some marking, so...

Answer (score 8):

As the `fit` library has been mentioned a few times, here's a suggestion using that. It requires nodes, so all the black dots are created using `\node`. Note that by changing the `node distance` you can modify how stretched out the figure should be, in the y and x direction.

The cross is drawn using a different technique, and relative to the nodes around it, so modifying the `node distance` will also change the cross.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  dot/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt,label={[label distance=0.3cm]#1}},
  node distance=0.6cm and 1.5cm,]

% draw left column of symbols
%      options                           node name   node label 
\node [dot={left:$v_h$}]                 (vh)        {};
\node [below=of vh]                      (vdots1)    {$\vdots$};
\node [below=of vdots1,dot={left:$v_2$}] (v2)        {};
\node [below=of v2,dot={left:$v_1$}]     (v1)        {};

% draw right column of symbols
\node [right=of vh,dot={right:$v_n$}]         (vn)     {};
\node [below=of vn]                           (vdots2) {$\vdots$};
\node [below=of vdots2,dot={}]                (vN)     {};
\node [below=of vN,dot={right:$v_{n-h+1}$}]   (vnh)    {};
\node [below=of vnh]                          (vdots3) {$\vdots$};
\node [below=of vdots3,dot={right:$v_{h+1}$}] (vh1)    {};


% draw lines between dots
\draw (vh) -- (vn);
\draw (v1) -- (vN) -- (v2) -- (vnh) -- (v1);

% draw cross in middle
\foreach \y in {-1,1} {
  \draw  ($(v2)!0.35!(vn) + (0,\y pt)$)  -- ($(vn)!0.35!(v2) + (0,\y pt)$);
  \draw  ($(vh)!0.35!(vN) + (0,\y pt)$)  -- ($(vN)!0.35!(vh) + (0,\y pt)$);
}

% draw rectangle around right column
\node [fit=(vh1)(vn),draw,rounded corners] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]